# How to center 2 buttons in Cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have an OS X app with 2 buttons next to each other. The buttons are nicely centered.

[image: Non-resized window]

But when I resize the window, the buttons stay at the same place.

[image: Resized window]

How do I align the buttons so that they're always centered when I resize the window?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using XCode4.6, by default this will be in Autolayout mode.

You need to change it to manual layout (Which I feel easier to perform this task)

[Download working model.](http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/6035993/resize-and-buttons-in-center-38k?da=y)

Steps how to do :

**Click on XIB**

**Uncheck Use Auto Layout**

[image]

**Go to Navigator -> Embed In Box**
[image]

**Select Box -> Attributes Inspector -> Title Position None & Border Type None.**
[image]

**Select texFiled -> Size Inspector**
[image]

**Select Box ->** 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Embed both buttons in custom view. You will get `Embed Objects In` option un Layout.

[image]

Autoresizing for custom view

[image]